# How would I refactor three similar methods in C#

Tags: c#, refactoring

What C# constructs would I use to refactor these three similar methods into one?

```
void func1()
  if (display.count != 0)
  {
    for (int i = display.count - 1; i >=0; --i)
    {
      if (display[i].test1())
        break;
    }
  }
}

void func2()
  if (display.count != 0)
  {
    for (int i = display.count - 1; i >=0; --i)
    {
      if (display[i].test2())
        break;
    }
  }
}

void func3()
  if (display.count != 0)
  {
    for (int i = display.count - 1; i >=0; --i)
    {
      if (display[i].test3())
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you even do this? Your code is quite simple and short, the first condition however is meaningless as it is already checked within the actual loop.

Comment: Do you really want to loop from `int i = display.count`? It should be `int i = display.count - 1`

Comment: @Dmitry -  yes, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would pass the method to call as a Function that returns a boolean and takes a Display (your object type as I asume) as an argument:

```
void TestFunc(Func<Display, bool> function)
{
    for (int i = display.count; i >=0; --i)
    {
      if (function(display[i]))
        break;
    }
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
TestFunc(d => d.test3());
```

Comment: Is this called a "delegate"?

Comment: @pingu  `Func<Display, bool>` is a delegate. The call `d => d.test3()` is a lambda expression